# Samsung Galaxy 3 will not go into recovery boot

Tags: samsung, recovery-mode, boot

Samsung Galaxy S3 won't boot. tried the 3 buttons goes to recovering boot and Samsung, then Galaxy S3, then blank. A few times I got it all the way to the recovery page, then android dies and says no command, then goes blank. Never giving me enough time to scroll down to error messages to delete. Any suggestions? If I try to turn it on sometimes shows a picture of a blank battery, sometimes an almost full green battery or vibrate then nothing. It won't start to use it in anyway.

Answer (score -1):

Here, you may need to flash your recovery again as it seems in problem.

To boot into recovery mode you can use adb command: **adb reboot recovery**. For this you need minimum requirements for adb. [Here](http://www.izzysoft.de/ftp/local/android/)  you can download this.

Comment: Your answer is missing core instructions for "*flash your recovery again*"

Comment: My first line was for that thing only. I just wanted to confirm that by proper booting in recovery. Sometimes we are unable to perform button task to open recovery. We need to check before taking big step.

Comment: This is a question-and-answer site, [not a forum](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/92107/192154): please don't add comments as answers. Use actual comments when seeking clarification of any issues.

Answer (score -1):

Let me make this short but sweet. If you had enabled **"USB Debugging"** on your device before this started happening to you, then you can flash another recovery using Odin, simple and easy.

[GO HERE](http://trueandroid.com/install-clockworkmod-recovery-6-0-4-4-on-galaxy-s3-gt-i9300-how-to/) ONLY if you are 110% sure that you have **"USB Debugging = enabled"** on your device.

** This tutorial is only for Galaxy S3 GT-I9300. Don’t try this guide on any other Android device. Also, we are not responsible for any damage caused due to the instruction given in this page. Try this at your own risk. However, it is very unlikely that your device will be damaged if you follow all the instructions as it is mentioned in the procedure. **

---

If you DO NOT have or cannot remember if you have **"USB Debugging = enabled"** on your device, then you want to use **Samsung KIES** to get back into your device. WARNING: Using Samsung KIES **WILL** delete the data on your device. You can find the process to use Samsung KIES => [RIGHT HERE](http://forum.xda-developers.com/galaxy-s3/general/guide-how-to-reinstall-stock-firmware-t1978840)

** I am not held responsible for anything bad that happens to your device such as bricking or whatever. Doing this is entirely up to you. Still, this is a whole lot safer than flashing, since it is an OFFICIAL method of reinstalling a firmware. Any issues you get should be redirected to Samsung, the creator of KIES **

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. Otherwise, your answer becomes useless in case the link dies. For further hints, please see: [How do I write a good answer](http://android.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer).